# Does craft have any build in function for countries like locales?

Tags: localization

I'm wondering if there's a build in craft function for displaying countries (countryCode and/or name)?

Just like it is for displaying locales:

```
craft.i18n.getAllLocales()
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of is to pull the data from the 'territories' part of a `craft/app/framework/i18n/data` file.

For 'en_us', that would be something like this:

```
{% set localeData = craft.i18n.getLocaleData('en_us') %}
{% set allTerritories = localeData.getAllTerritories() %}
```

Comment: How do I know which variable names to use for the "allTerritories" variable from localData.getAllTerritories? A twig {{ dump() }} didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Disrecard my last comment. Turning on devMode made the "dump" function available.